# Way to have a function like urandom_range(); which will return unique values?

Tags: system-verilog

I want to have a urandom_range(); which will not repeat a value once its picked in a simulation ? If it has exhausted its supply of 'available' numbers, then perhaps it can repeat .

Is there any keyword in systemverilog which will help quickly to get around this ?

Not a SV expert here so an example would really help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable with **randc** identifier. This is called 'cyclical random' and will ensure exactly what you are requiring.

**Note:** This requires a license that supports randomization and random variables. Most commercial simulators do provide this but at a higher cost. If you are constrained by this and need to only use the system calls - $urandom or $urandom_range, I would implement something like a queue that tracks all the values returned.

```
function automatic void find_unique_num();

    int c;
    int vals[$];
    bit found;
    do begin
      c = $urandom_range(10, 1);
      foreach(vals[i]) 
        if (c == vals[i]) found = 1;
    end
    while (!found);
    vals.push_back(c);
    return c

endfunction
```

Comment: You could have replaced the `foreach` loop with the `inside` operator: `do c = $urandom_range(10,1); while (c inside {vals});`. But in any case, you need to check when vars has completed the cycle so you can reset it.

Comment: @dave_59 - much more efficient way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`randc` does exactly this. (cyclic randomization)

```
class A;
  randc bit[7:0] m;
endclass
```

Each time you call `randomize()` on the same object, it will not repeat value for `m` until all possible values have been given.

Simulators have limits on how large the cyclic value can be, but the standard requires a minimum of 8-bits. If you have a larger value, then you can use the `inside` operator.

```
class A;
      rand bit[23:0] r;
      bit [23:0] list[$];
      constraint c { !(r inside {list}); }
      function void post_randomize();
        list.push_back(r);
      endfunction   
endclass
```

If you really expect to cycle through the list, it might be simpler to build the list first, and then `shuffle` through the list.

```
bit [7:0] list[20];

for(int i=0;i<20;i++) list[i] = i+10; // range 10-29
list.shuffle();
// cycle through list[0] ... list[29]
list.shuffle();
// cycle through list[0] ... list[29]
```